# Database not getting exported in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i am trying to export database from phpmyadmin its size is large i.e:16 GB so i changed the php.ini file wi these

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M ;
post_max_size = 120M ;
max_execution_time = 120 ;
```

but still i am having trouble in import and export of db .

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest that you use the mysqldump.exe to dump your database.

This website would guide you on it:
https://www.lullabot.com/articles/importexport-large-mysql-databases

Comment: i have tried bigdump.php isn't it just used for import ?

Comment: Yup. You will be able to export it via following the instructions in the link above.